# Facebook embed video player api not rendering iframe video outputs in local html files

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, video-player

Hi when i copied the fb embed player example code and paste in my local html file, the video is not rendered. where as when i try it in some online html editors like w3 schools , it works fine. What is the reason behind it? The html code is below:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Your Website Title</title>
</head>
<body>

  <!-- Load Facebook SDK for JavaScript -->
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        appId      : '{your-app-id}',
        xfbml      : true,
        version    : 'v2.5'
      });

      // Get Embedded Video Player API Instance
      var my_video_player;
      FB.Event.subscribe('xfbml.ready', function(msg) {
        if (msg.type === 'video') {
          my_video_player = msg.instance;
        }
      });
    };

    (function(d, s, id){
       var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
       if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
       js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
       js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
       fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
     }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
  </script>

  <!-- Your embedded video player code -->
  <div  
    class="fb-video" 
    data-href="https://www.facebook.com/facebook/videos/10153231379946729/" 
    data-width="500" 
    data-allowfullscreen="true"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you checked the browser console for errors/messages from the Facebook SDK? By “local html file” you mean you simply open the file in your browser directly, without a local web server? That could be the reason already, some of this stuff requires that you use it on pages opened via HTTP(S) in your browser. Get a local web server like XAMPP for your development.

Comment: yes, have to load it on a web server. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you just use Embed video code from fb?

```html
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Ffacebook%2Fvideos%2F10153231379946729%2F&show_text=0&width=560" width="560" height="315" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" allowFullScreen="true"></iframe>
```

Here is also the same code on my local html page screenshot:
[image]

Comment: I need the video player Api , so that i can control video activities like play, pause, etc. @Nezir

Comment: I think it is due to CORB

Comment: Same problem !  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-video-player code with javascript sdk showing nothing from this page